# Laravel Union with and in join option

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a native Php/Mysql Query which I need to convert to Laravel query. I'm pretty new in the world of laravel and finding it interesting but I'm on this issue for over 3 days.

Here's my native Php/Mysl query

```
$sql = "SELECT a.employeeID, a.nric, a.fullName, b.salary, c.total_allowance, c.year, c.month, c.period, d.deptName, c.aws, c.additionals,
           c.id, a.date_of_birth, c.total_additional
    from employees a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN salary b ON a.employeeID = b.employeeID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN payrolls c ON a.employeeID = c.employeeID and year = '$presyear' and month = '$presmonth' and period = '$period'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN department d ON a.designation = d.id 
    UNION 
    SELECT a.employeeID, a.nric, a.fullName, b.salary, c.total_allowance, c.year, c.month, c.period, d.deptName, c.aws, c.additionals,
           c.id, a.date_of_birth, c.total_additional
    from employees a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN salary b ON a.employeeID = b.employeeID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN payrolls c ON a.employeeID = c.employeeID and year != '' and month != '' and period != ''
    LEFT OUTER JOIN department d ON a.designation = d.id 
    WHERE c.net_salary != ''";
```

It gives me the result I want but I don't know to you guys maybe you want some adjustments on this one.

Now this is as far as I can get in Lravel

```
$result = Payroll::select('payrolls.id','payrolls.employeeID','fullName','month','year','period','department.deptName','payrolls.aws',
                      'payrolls.adjustment','payrolls.allowances','payrolls.alencashment','payrolls.housing_allowance',
                      'payrolls.med_reimburse','payrolls.overtime_hours','payrolls.overtime_pay','payrolls.reimbursement','payrolls.tips',
                      'net_salary','payrolls.total_additional','payrolls.total_allowance','payrolls.total_deduction','payrolls.total_cpf')
              ->join('employees', 'payrolls.employeeID', '=', 'employees.employeeID','left')
              ->join('department', 'employees.designation', '=', 'department.id','left')
              ->where('payrolls.year','=',$presyear)
              ->where('payrolls.month','=',$presmonth)
              ->where('payrolls.period','=',$period);
```

I dont know exactly how to do the unions and all the and inside the outer join as what I did in native.

I'm using Laravel 4.2.17

Thanks.

Comment: Anyone Please. Hehehe.

Answer (score 0):

I do not prove it but you can do something like

```
 $first = \DB::table('employees')->select(['employees.employeeID', 'employees.nric', 'employees.fullName', 'salary.salary', 'payrolls.total_allowance', 'payrolls.year', 'payrolls.month', 'payrolls.period', 'department.deptName', 'payrolls.aws', 'payrolls.additionals', 'payrolls.id', 'employees.id', 'employees.date_of_birth', 'payrolls.total_additional'])
->leftJoin('salary', 'employees.id', '=', 'salary.employeeId')
->leftJoin('payrolls', function($join)
{
    $join->on( 'employees.id', '=', 'payrolls.employeeId')->on('year', '!=', '')->on('month', '!=', '')->on('period', '!=', '');
})
->leftJoin('department', 'employees.designation', '=', 'department.id')
->where('payrolls.net_salary', '!=', '');


\DB::table('employees')->select(['employees.employeeID', 'employees.nric', 'employees.fullName', 'salary.salary', 'payrolls.total_allowance', 'payrolls.year', 'payrolls.month', 'payrolls.period', 'department.deptName', 'payrolls.aws', 'payrolls.additionals', 'payrolls.id', 'employees.id', 'employees.date_of_birth', 'payrolls.total_additional'])
->leftJoin('salary', 'employees.id', '=', 'salary.employeeId')
->leftJoin('payrolls', function($join)
{
    $join->on( 'employees.id', '=', 'payrolls.employeeId')->on('year', '=', $presyear)->on('month', '=', $presmonth)->on('period', '=', $period);
})
->leftJoin('department', 'employees.designation', '=', 'department.id')->union($first)->get();
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries.

If you can't go on you can always use \DB::select see https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database#running-queries.